# c#:getting longitude and latitude from address

Tags: c#, geocoding

I am designing a website which converts and stores longitude and latitude of the entered address.iused google geocoding api for this purpose and the code I used to convert address to longitude and latitude is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Geocoding.Google;
using Geocoding;
public partial class test3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() {  };
        Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode(TextBox1.Text).ToArray();
        foreach (Address adrs in addresses)
        {
            Response.Write("address:"+adrs);
        }
    }
}
```

And for the input Delhi,India instead of getting the longitude and latitude values i am getting more specific address again

```
address:New Delhi, Delhi, India
```

please somebody who used google api before help me to  modify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Coordinates`

Replace This:

```
Response.Write("address:"+adrs);
```

With This:

```
Response.Write("address:"+adrs.Coordinates);
```

Comment: @user3322356: You are welcome Dear :) have a nice day

Comment: sure i will..i am doing a project is there any way i can keep in touch with you?

Comment: @user3322356: sure dear , send me a test mail to  my personal email id`sudha4projects@gmail.com`

Comment: thank you very much..:)soon i will send you the mail.thanks for the answer once again.

Comment: @user3322356: sure :) You are welcome ,I'm glad tobe help of you.